# Granger causality test: do I need to make the data stationarity?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, granger-causality

I am carrying out a Granger causality test for multivariate series in the R software but I have a few doubts.

1. Should I make the data stationary before carrying out the test?
2. Can I use the "lmtest" package in R to do the test for multivariate series?

Comment: Dave Giles' blog post ["Testing for Granger Causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html) (and any links in it) is all you need. Just read it carefully. When it comes to R implementation, look for designated functions, like `causality` in "vars" package or `granger.test` in "MSBVAR" package. See also multiple earlier posts here on Cross Validated.

Comment: for the first one Dave Giles' blog post answered my question. But im still confused on which function in R to test granger causality. What i have understood is to use the causality function in "vars" and carry the steps of Dave Giles' blog post. Is it right ? Can i use a function such as lmtest designated for bivariate time series on multivariate time series ?

Comment: I am not sure. I have not used `lmtest` that much before.